# Why was I told that xxx in the web address xxx.yyy.com is not a subdomain?

Tags: configuration, iis-6, subdomain, cname

**edit: more to the address than I had given in the example. It has a subfolder??  https://some_external_website.com/bh/public**

Is it correct to say that xxx is a subdomain of yyy.com written as xxx.yyy.com

**email I sent to the BIG IT dept: names changed to protect the innocent**
Additional Info:Please create an entry that will map the subdomain xxx.yyy.com to https://some_external_website.com/bh/public
this is an externally hosted web application.  Please call me if you have any questions.

--end of message--

About an hour later I get a call because they don't know what I want, I was told that xxx is not a subdomain.  The correct definition subdomain it would have to be   xxx.www.yyy.com.

Comment: They are wrong. Why, we can't know.

Comment: Then again, your request should not include the `https://`, which is a protocol. They can't redirect a subdomain to a protocol: they'll link the subdomain to an IP, the webserver on that IP will redirect to another URI.

Comment: So what do I need to do to get to the result I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first component of a "domain name" is always the hostname.  We can view a domain name as consisting of a hostname followed by one or more domain components.  Each domain component is a subdomain of the component to it's immediate right.  In xxx.yyy.zzz, xxx is the hostname (typically of a single machine, unless some kind of load balancing is going on), and yyy is a sub-domain of the zzz top-level domain.  Colloquially we usually refer to zzz as the top-level domian, yyy as "the domain", and all other names to the left (excluding leftmost which is the hostname) as sub-domains.  I'll add the disclaimer that I am by no means a DNS expert but to the best of my knowledge this would be why they aren't understanding your question.  The hostname is not a "domain" per-se, i.e. it defines a single machine rather than a group (domain) of machines.

Comment: thanks, as an aside, I had logically derived that I should describe the url using xxx.yyy. notation.  Apparently this is the common way to describe urls...